# How to reach diffrent Subdomains on Guest from the host?

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine, apache-http-server, subdomain

I am trying to set up multiple websites, test and live, as subdomains in a ubuntu-server 22.04 as guest in a Virtualbox. Their sole purpose is for testing scripts, they not have to be seen by the web (just for system updates) or something other then the host. I installed apache2, php and mysql.
Then i adjust the Virtualbox via NAT for port forwarding and create a rule where the host port 8000 forwarded to guest port 80. Then i restart the machine and can reach the apache2 hello-world-site in the browser with *localhost:8000*.

That is what i expected. Now i wish to configure two subdomains. I create a file `website.conf` with this text inside:

```
## Test
 <VirtualHost *:80>
   DocumentRoot /var/www/html/test/
   ServerName test.website.com
 </VirtualHost>

## Live
<VirtualHost *:80>
   DocumentRoot /var/www/html/live
   ServerName live.website.com
 </VirtualHost>
```

And set my `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf`

```
ServerName website.com
```

Then restart apache with systemctl.
After that, i configure `/etc/hosts` on the host:

```
127.0.0.1:8000    website.com
```

Now i am trying to reach the websites via the browser.
I try *test.website.com* and *live.website.com*, but both say
***"Server not found"***
When i try *test.localhost:8000*, *live.localhost:8000* and *localhost:8000* i get to the site behind *test.website.com*, the default.

`apache2ctl -t` yields:

"Syntax OK"

`apache2ctl -S` yields:

```
VirtualHost configuration:
*:80                   is a NameVirtualHost
         default server test.website.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/website.conf:2)
         port 80 namevhost test.website.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/website.conf:2)
         port 80 namevhost live.website.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/website.conf:8)
ServerRoot: "/etc/apache2"
Main DocumentRoot: "/var/www/html"
Main ErrorLog: "/var/log/apache2/error.log"
Mutex watchdog-callback: using_defaults
Mutex rewrite-map: using_defaults
Mutex default: dir="/var/run/apache2/" mechanism=default 
Mutex mpm-accept: using_defaults
PidFile: "/var/run/apache2/apache2.pid"
Define: DUMP_VHOSTS
Define: DUMP_RUN_CFG
User: name="www-data" id=33 not_used
Group: name="www-data" id=33 not_used
```

How can I enable both Subdomains served by the guest to reach via the browser of the host, i doesnt matter if with *.localhost:8000 or the URL?

Comment: If you're reaching the default site on your VM I'd suggest the VirtualBox side of things is working, and it's an issue with your site config. You might be better asking over on https://serverfault.com/ about that side of things.

Comment: @KeithLangmead Thanks for the suggestion, i tried at over there. In first place, i came here because the question wizard there suggested to come here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your hosts file configuration is invalid as the hosts file only maps a domain name to an IP address, ports shouldn't appear in them.

In addition, you want to map `live.website.com` and `test.website.com`, but you currently have an (invalid) entry for `website.com`. The hosts file is a plain mapping, without any notion of subdomain.

You need an entry like the following in your hosts file

```
127.0.0.1 live.website.com test.website.com
```

Once you have such an entry, you should be able to access both sites using `http://live.website.com:8000/` and `http://test.website.com:8000/`.

If that's not the case, then you also need to add the port in the Apache `ServerName` directive (or add a `ServerAlias` with the port).